# RabbitMQ invalid credentials with valid information

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, credentials, spring-amqp

I'm working with some Java/Spring web applications and RabbitMQ.
I have App1 and App2 on the **same** tomcat server at the address `192.168.0.101`.
They both communicate with a RabbitMQ server located at : `192.168.0.100`.

App1 has this configuration in the spring context:

```
<bean id="connectionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory"
    destroy-method="destroy">
    <property name="host" value="192.168.0.100" />
    <property name="username" value="app" />
    <property name="password" value="guest" />
    <property name="virtualHost" value="/" />
</bean>
```

App2 has the same config except a different username, let's say:

```
<bean id="connectionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory"
    destroy-method="destroy">
    <property name="host" value="192.168.0.100" />
    <property name="username" value="app2" />
    <property name="password" value="guest" />
    <property name="virtualHost" value="/" />
</bean>
```

The problem is that App1 can connect successfully to the RabbitMQ server, and App2 has always a `invalid credentials` error in the RabbitMQ logs.

Here is the permissions list for these users:

```
Listing permissions in vhost "/" ...
app    .*    .*    .*
app2   .*    .*    .*
```

And here is what I get when I try to log in with the API (with both users): `curl -i -u app:guest http://192.168.0.100:15672/api/whoami` and `curl -i -u app2:guest http://192.168.0.100:15672/api/whoami`

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Server: MochiWeb/1.1 WebMachine/1.10.0 (never breaks eye contact)
Date: Mon, 30 Jun 2014 14:58:37 GMT
Content-Length: 57

{"error":"not_authorised","reason":"Not management user"}
```

which seems pretty normal, I think, each user is recognized as valid user but not authorized for management. When I set the management tag for app2, I get this :

```
curl -i -u app2:guest http://192.168.0.100:15672/api/whoami
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: MochiWeb/1.1 WebMachine/1.10.0 (never breaks eye contact)
Date: Mon, 30 Jun 2014 15:14:29 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 80
Cache-Control: no-cache

{"name":"app2","tags":"management","auth_backend":"rabbit_auth_backend_internal"}
```

I know this is a lot of code but this is all I get, and I'm about to give up and never know what's going on. I really don't understand what I am doing wrong because configurations looks exactly the same.

What do you think ?

Thanks in advance ! A lot.

EDIT:
Here is the rabbitMq log line that I get when app2 tries to connect:

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 30-Jun-2014::16:42:38 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.1241.0> (192.168.0.101:52871 -> 192.168.0.100:5672):
{handshake_error,starting,0,
             {amqp_error,access_refused,
                         "PLAIN login refused: user 'app2' - invalid credentials",
                         'connection.start_ok'}}
```

EDIT2:
And here is the Java error log that I get at the moment the app2 tries to connect:

```
    Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.PossibleAuthenticationFailureException: Possibly caused by authentication failure
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.start(AMQConnection.java:355)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:516)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:545)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:181)
        ... 48 more
    Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: connection error; reason: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at com.rabbitmq.utility.ValueOrException.getValue(ValueOrException.java:67)
        at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:33)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:343)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.privateRpc(AMQChannel.java:216)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.rpc(AMQChannel.java:202)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.start(AMQConnection.java:347)
        ... 51 more
    Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:196)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
        ...
```

Comment: Makes no sense to me; can you run wireshark and look at the `Connection.Start-Ok` packet? You should see the user/pw a little bit after `PLAIN`.

Comment: Also, check the user on the admin page, is the checkbox marked 'Can log in with password' ?

Comment: Makes no sense to me too ! We tried Wireshark, and I see the packet, and at the end I see exactly the username and the password which are correct (I changed the username here in my post to generic usernames) but I see a "red line" in wireshark, after the `Start-Ok` packet with a `RST,ACK` flags..

Oh, and the user has the "Can log with password" checkbox checked...
We're analyzing the packets for the other user for comparison.

Comment: I just tried to remake `app2` based on the `app` config (just changed the java classes) but config files are now exactly the same...didn't work either. We even tried to shut down `app` to avoid any possible connection conflict (didn't work). And we even tried to use `app` credentials (which work for `app`), with `app2`,...didn't work ( same RabbitMQ error log `invalid credentials` ...etc. for the other username).
Maybe it's some kind of lower level tomcat config issue ?

Comment: Make sure you connect to the right vhost, or just your user wildcard permission for all entities in all vhost for rwx to diagnose is this a root of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Because time was against us I decided to uninstall and purge completely Tomcat from the server and do a fresh install then put each app one by one.

Guess what, they both connect successfully to RabbitMQ without any warning/error of any kind.

So, if anyone here know **how a specific (external) tomcat configuration can prevent ONE app in particular from communicating with RabbitMQ** you're welcome ...

By "external" I mean "not an app-related" configuration. I am not really a Tomcat expert, I know there is many files, and many ways to configure it, and I am still curious to know what happened.

Comment: I don't see how this has/had anything to do with Tomcat - your question said your connection factory config was in Spring (you are not using JNDI). Very weird.